# Is it correct to use modules to handle form class elements?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

I have a `Private Sub Modify()` inside a form class *A* to handle the behaviour of a button or label (both belong to the same *A* class).
Let's say it does this:

```
Private Sub Modify()
    btnFoo.Enabled = True
    lblBar.Text = "labelbar"
 End Sub
```

If i move my `Private Sub Modify()` from the form class A to a module B and name it `Public Sub Modify` all I have to do to change the behaviour of the same button or label is something like this:

```
Public Sub Modify()
    A.btnFoo.Enabled = True
    A.lblBar.Text = "labelbar"
End Sub
```

But would this be aproppiate, considering the modules are some kind of *static* elements?
I would like to know the propper way, so i could keep up with good practices.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's almost never a good idea for a module, class, or anything else to access another object's properties multiple levels deep like that.  If nothing else, it breaks [The Law of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter).  In more general terms, it's not a good idea to have anything outside of the form manipulate any of a form's controls directly.  I think it's regrettable that controls are public, by default, in the first place.  It would be better to leave the `Modify` method on the form and just make it `Public` if you need to call it from outside the form.

Comment: very useful answer @StevenDoggart , thanks. Now I'll keep the LoD in mind whenever i have to develop any OOP solution.

Answer (score 1):

If you go down this road, you'll end up having lots of Modules changing lots of stuff in lots of Forms... You will hate that code complexity if you want to extend the program with new features or fix a bug.

A better rule is: Do all the stuff regarding a Form, in that Form.

Why do you actually want to extract that code into a Module? Is it because you will do the same thing in many Forms? Under these circumstances it makes *maybe* sense to extract such code, but don't let the Module be aware of a specific form. Instead you could do

```
Public Sub Modify(button As Button, label As Label)
    button.Enabled True
    label.Text = "labelbar"
End Sub
```

and call that in many Forms with

```
Private Sub ChangeElements()
    Modify(btnFoo, lblBar)
End Sub
```

But again, it is better to leave such things in the Form.